# Serializing Nested Attributes Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have the following code and can't seem to get my JSON to output as per my serializer.

I receive the following log `[active_model_serializers] Rendered SimpleJobSerializer with Hash`

My controller is as below:

```
# Jobs Controller

def home
    return_limit = 2

    @dev_jobs = Job.where(category: 'developer').limit(return_limit)
    @marketing_jobs = Job.where(category: 'marketing').limit(return_limit)
    @sales_jobs = Job.where(category: 'sales').limit(return_limit)


    @jobs = {
      developer: @dev_jobs,
      marketing: @marketing_jobs,
      sales: @sales_jobs
    }

    render json: @jobs, each_serializer: SimpleJobSerializer
  end
```

And my serializer:

```
class SimpleJobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :company, :job_type, :date

  def date
    d = object.created_at
    d.strftime("%d %b")
  end
end
```

I am receiving the full API response but expect to only receive `title`, `company`, `job_type` and `date`.

It's worth mentioning the jobs model is completely flat and there are currently no associations to take into account. It seems to be just the nesting of the jobs into the @jobs object that's stopping serialization.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you expecting the json at the top level to be `{ developer : [...], marketing: [...], sales: [...] }`?

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for your reply. That's exactly what I am expecting the JSON to be. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_serializer` expects you to pass an array but here you're passing a hash:

```
@jobs = {
  developer: @dev_jobs,
  marketing: @marketing_jobs,
  sales: @sales_jobs
}
```

Since you want that structure, I'd recommend two approachs depending on which you prefer.  One is to change the serializer which should control the format:

```
class JobsSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :developer, :marketing, :sales

  def developer
    json_array(object.where(category: "developer"))
  end

  def marketing
    json_array(object.where(category: "marketing"))
  end

  def sales
    json_array(object.where(category: "sales"))
  end

  def json_array(jobs)
    ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(jobs, each_serializer: SimpleJobSerializer)
  end
end
```

You can still leave your current serializer as is:

```
class SimpleJobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :company, :job_type, :date

  def date
    d = object.created_at
    d.strftime("%d %b")
  end
end
```

Or option 2 would be to do this in the controller:

```
@jobs = {
  developer: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@dev_Jobs, each_serializer: SimpleJobSerializer),
  marketing: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@marketing_jobs, each_serializer: SimpleJobSerializer),
  sales: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@sales_jobs, each_serializer: SimpleJobSerializer)
}

render json: @jobs
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. The only slight change I had to make was `ActiveModel::Serializer::ArraySerializer.new(@dev_jobs, serializer: SimpleJobSerializer)` because in the newest version of AMS it's slightly restructured

Comment: In fact it's even recommended `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new(@dev_jobs, serializer: SimpleJobSerializer)` with collectionSerializer in the new AMS. Thanks for all your help!